# How can I reuse a table name after deletion (in DynamoDB)?

Tags: table, dynamodb

I am working through a tutorial which requires creating a DynamoDB table with a specific name. On my first pass at creating the table I did something out sync with the tutorial, so I deleted the table with the intention of starting over again. However now when I try to create a table with the same name I get the error "Table with that name already exists."

I could use a different name, but the tutorial is particularly long and complex, and I would prefer to stay exactly in sync.

Is it possible to reuse a table name? Do I just need to wait for the original name to be recyclable?

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question:

I waited about ten minutes and then the error went away. It appears that the name is in a cache which is periodically refreshed.